# Хостер VDS с минимальным пингом в Северо-Западном регионе и хорошим аптаймом

Tags: хостинг

Собственно нужен хостер, такой, чтобы не было проблем. Обычно работаю с Linode, у них дикий аптайм, но тут появился телекоммуникационный проект, и для SIP'а нужен минимальный пинг от пользователей до сервера.

Слышал много ругани про Скалакси и Селектел.

Перепродающие Hetzner не интересуют по причине размещения в Европе и, как результат, длинного пинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hetzner кстати с пингом нормально, он нифига не длинный. А селектел вполне рабочий ДЦ. единственный раз упал недавно из-за глупостей :)

Пинг, еще зависит от скорости твоего соединения, так что тут двоякий вопрос.

**//upd**

вот кстати, у меня к селектелу пинг совершенно другой.

время - 16мс среднее

а к hetzner - 58мс среднее, разница в 3 раза, но если учесть что до серверов в США пинг более 200мс -  что вообще катастрофа!

То германия тут лучший вариант + цена/качество услуг.

У селектела сервера дороже чем у хетзнера, примерно в 8-12 раз. а потеря и отклик при пинге не такая высокая.

Опять же многое зависит от каналов по которым идет соединение. Т.к. из Питера до германии скорость может быть 58мс до селектела 20, а вот если из владикавказа то и до селектела пинг может возрасти до 58, а до германии допустим 80мс. тут уже потери будут другими.

Это скорости замера с серверов селектела на хетзнер и сам же селектел, но в москве. пинги из питера.

```
PING hetzner.com (213.133.107.241): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 213.133.107.241: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=46.115 ms
64 bytes from 213.133.107.241: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=45.956 ms
64 bytes from 213.133.107.241: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=45.610 ms

PING6(selectel.ru) 2a02:2d8:0:81e:232a::1 --> 2a00:ab00::2
16 bytes from 2a00:ab00::2, icmp_seq=0 hlim=61 time=11.865 ms
16 bytes from 2a00:ab00::2, icmp_seq=1 hlim=61 time=11.753 ms
16 bytes from 2a00:ab00::2, icmp_seq=2 hlim=61 time=11.803 ms
```

Но еси нужен именно VDS, то советую брать больше чем имеешь, т.к. нет swap раздела и ты его никак не создашь на машинах селектела.  [Вот пост на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/89851/) про OpenVZ.

Comment: ```$ ping hetzner.com
PING hetzner.com (213.133.107.241) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dedihetzner.your-server.de (213.133.107.241): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=51.0 ms
$ ping selectel.ru
PING selectel.ru (188.93.16.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 188.93.16.26: icmp_req=1 ttl=60 time=2.72 ms```
Разница - в 20 раз. От скорости соединения может сильно зависеть только если на клиент на модеме сидит.

За селектел спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Вообще-то уже довольно давно, версии эдак с 2.6.35, под swap не обязательно создавать партицию, а [достаточно](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swap_file) и файла.

Comment: Это если Xen/KVM или любая другая виртуализация, где можно использовать собственное ядро со всеми делами. Но там, часто, нет проблем и виртуальный диск переразбить. Со столь любимым хостерами OpenVZ (его второе имя — оверселлинг, как-никак) этот фокус не прокатит, `swapon` внутри VE радостно откажет, дескать, нет прав.

Да, у OpenVZ есть такая штука, как VSwap, но он настраивается хостером, а не клиентом. Нет — можно, конечно, попросить, но результат, скорее всего, будет немного предсказуем.

Comment: Во-во команда swapon /swapfile нифига работать не будет!

Ибо как написал @drdaeman нет прав на выполнение, я как-то раз сел так в лужу. Так что @pirj ты не прав!